# Property of an algebra of sets

Tags: measure-theory

$\mathscr{A} $ is an algebra of sets. Prove $A_1,..,A_{n} \in \mathscr{A} \Rightarrow \bigcup^{\infty}_{k=1}A_k \in \mathscr{A} $

$x\in \bigcup^{\infty}_{k=1}A_k $ means that there exists $k$ such that $x \in A_k$.

How to do it by induction? Is it and induction by n? For $n=1$, $A_1 \in \mathscr{A}$. I assume that the statement is true for all $n$. It means that $\bigcup^{n}_{k=1}A_k \in \mathscr{A}$. Now I have to check it for $n+1$. $\bigcup^{n+1}_{k=1}A_k = (\bigcup^{n}_{k=1}A_k)  \cup A_n$. And now by induction hypothesis $\bigcup^{n}_{k=1}A_k \in \mathscr{A}$, by asuumption $A_n \in \mathscr{A}$, so union of these two things also is an algebra of sets (from definiton). Is that correct?

Comment: It is correct if it is your aim to prove that $A_1,\dots,A_2\in\mathscr A\implies\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\in\mathscr A$ is true for every $n\in\mathbb N$ (not the infinite union which is not necessarily an element of $\mathscr A$).

Comment: Ok, now I understand. If set fulfill this condition then it's called sigma-algebra. I have one more question. What would be an example that $A_1,...,A_n \in \mathscr{A} $ but the infinite union is not an element of $\mathscr{A}$?

Comment: Let $X$ be a set that is infinite and not countable and let $A\in\mathscr A$ iff $A$ is finite or $A^{\complement}$ is finite. Then $\mathscr A$ is an algebra that contains singletons, but not it will not contain $B=\bigcup_{i=1}\{x_i\}$ if $B$ is not finite.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true for an arbitrary algebra.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra

An algebra needs only to be closed under the union  of finitely many subsets.